# How do I use the watch and jobs commands together in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, watch

How do I use the `watch` command with `jobs` command, so that I can monitor when a background job is finished?

I execute it as follows, but I do not get the output from jobs:

```
watch jobs
```

If I run jobs by itself, I get the following with my test background job:

```
jobs
[1]+  Running                 nohup cat /dev/random >/dev/null &
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `watch` command is documented as follows:

```
SYNOPSIS
   watch  [-dhvt]  [-n  <seconds>] [--differences[=cumulative]] [--help]
          [--interval=<sec-onds>] [--no-title] [--version] <command>
[...]
NOTE
   Note that command is given to "sh -c" which means that you may need to
   use extra quoting to get the desired effect.
```

The part about giving the command to `sh -c` means the `jobs` command you are running via `watch` is running in a different shell session than the one that spawned the job, so it cannot be seen that other shell.  The problem is fundamentally that `jobs` is a shell built-in and must be run in the shell that spawned the jobs you want to see.

The closest you can get is to use a while loop in the shell that spawned the job:

```
$ while true; do jobs; sleep 10; done
```

You could define a function in your shell startup script to make that easier to use:

```
myjobwatch() { while true; do jobs; sleep 5; done; }
```

Then you just have to type `myjobwatch`.

Comment: I add a `clear`. `N=1; while true; do jobs; sleep ${N}; clear; done;`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a loop, I tend to use `watch` with a `grep` for my running job, eg

```
watch 'ps u | grep rsync'
```

Not perfect, but better than a while loop :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a while loop and make a function for this command:

```
while true; do echo -ne "`jobs`\r"; sleep 1;  done
```

Answer (score 0):

I can accomplish the same with

```
watch 'ps -aef | grep 23774'
```

where the number `23774` is the process-id of my job in the same session.